# GOLANG | Как распарсить строку

Tags: парсер, golang

Имею строку (`<<GRADIENT>>Hello<</GRADIENT>> <<GREEN>>world<</GREEN>> <<UNDERSCORE>>all<</UNDERSCORE>>`)

Как я могу получить слова, расположенные между `<<GRADIENT>>` и `<</GRADIENT>>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы пользовался [регулярными выражениями](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`<<GRADIENT>>([^<>]*)<</GRADIENT>>`)
    str := `<<GRADIENT>>Hello<</GRADIENT>> <<GREEN>>world<</GREEN>> <<UNDERSCORE>>all<</UNDERSCORE>>`
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    if match != nil {
        fmt.Println("Между <<GRADIENT>> и <</GRADIENT>>: ", match[1])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Ничего нет")
    }
}
```

Выражение `<<GRADIENT>>([^<>]*)<</GRADIENT>>` ищет строку, которая состоит из префикса `<<GRADIENT>>`, затем идёт произвольная подстрока, в которой нет символов `<` и `>`, и заканчивается суффиксом `<</GRADIENT>>`.

Метод `FindStringSubmatch` ищет строку, подходящую под описание, и если находит, возвращает массив из двух элементов. `mathc[0]` - вся найденная строка, `match[1]` - та часть строки, которая соответствует первой группе, т.е. части регулярного выражения в скобках. А в скобках у нас, как вы помните, `([^<>]*)` - та часть строки, которая между префиксом и суффиксом.

Метод [`FindStringSubmatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) ищет первую подходящую строку. Если у вас в строке несколько градиентов, то этот метод найдёт только один. Метод [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) найдёт все сразу.